# append a char to a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, char, append, jtextarea

So I'm working on making a class that will "type" letters into a JTextArea, pausing between each letter to make it look like someone is typing. The only way I can come up with is using output.append(char) in a loop with a pause. The only problem... you can only append Strings to JTextAreas.

So is there any way to convert a char to a string so that I can append it letter by letter???

Here is my code so far:

```
import objectdraw.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TypeWriter extends ActiveObject
                        implements Drawable {

  private char [] letter;
  private JTextArea cp;

  public TypeWriter(String sentence, JTextArea console) {

    /* break string into characters and save the console
     * for later use
     */
    letter = new char[sentence.length()];
    cp = console;

    for(int i=0; i<sentence.length(); i++) {
      letter[i] = sentence.charAt(i);
    }

    start();

  }

  public void run() {

    // append each letter, pausing between them
    for( char s : letter ) {
      cp.append(new String(s));
      pause(50);
    }

  }

  /* More methods for the 
   * Drawable interface...
   */

}
```

Comment: How do you convert *anything* in Java to a string?  Begins with t, ends with g... ;-)  Note that the techniques so far suggested share the same (probable) defect with your original code... your UI is locked up while the phantom typist is at work.

Comment: Yeah the .toString() method.... it didn't work. I got an error, it said...

    char cannot be dereferenced

Comment: Sorry - you probably tried it on a char, not a Character.  You'd need to convert to Character first.  The shorthand version for this, which is very heavily optimized by the compiler, is to just append to an empty string, e.g., - String bar = "" + 'x';.

Comment: @Ed Ah okay, I've seen people use Characters but didn't know what the difference was between Character and char. Also I know my UI is locked up, it works out to my favor that way because I'm building a little text-based adventure game. It's project I'm working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use characters.

```
String foo = "This is a String";
for (int i = 0; i < foo.length(); i++)
{
    String subString = foo.substring(i, i+1);
    cp.append(subString);
    pause(50);
}
```

Comment: I like your solution better then mine

Comment: Ahhh that makes alot more sense. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 3):

Use the String(char[] value) constructor so

```
String s = "";
s += Character.toString('s');
```